# Display SQL query output in cell A1 of an Excel Sheet

Tags: sql, excel, database

As a part of my job, I weekly have to send some updated data to my boss.
These datas consist in really simple SQL queries ("SELECT number_of_costumers FROM database where year=2022" for example), but there are quite a few queries to do, so even running each query, pasting it into an excel sheet one by one often take me a lot of time. I was wondering if it was possible to make this process automatic? Is it possible to directly do SQL queries from Excel (without importing the whole database in Excel), so that the result is displayed in cell A1 for the first query, A2 for the second, etc.?

I am quite new to Excel, so I really don't know how to proceed, may I ask your help?
Thanks by advance!

Comment: Not sure about that, but could you create a script that generates your output as one single blob? Like a bunch of UNIONed queries? Then you could paste output into excel and create formulas to pull the data you need.

Comment: Please think also about your job-security. If your job can be replaced with some Excel then you are in danger

Comment: Powerquery should do that for you. Or search for vba ado excel - you will get a lot of answers.